# Touchscreen stops working

Tags: xorg, gdm, touchscreen

I am working with some Ubuntu systems to control some smart home things. I run Ubuntu on a industrial PC with an industrial touchscreen display. Everything was working fine. Since some time ago the touchscreen has stopped working after some time. I didn't reboot the PC. I have the same problem on more than one Ubuntu system, so I think the problem is a software problem. I have looked in the logs and I always see this if the problem disappears:

```
Jul 27 15:02:28 byk-station /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1021]: source device 10: history size 6400 overflowing for touch 3088  
Jul 27 15:02:50 byk-station /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1021]: message repeated 1585 times: [source device 10: history size 6400 overflowing for touch 3088]
```

This message comes often then. With this message the touchscreen stops working. Normally there helps a reboot, but I need to find a solution for the problem. I couldn't add the whole syslog input here because it is too long.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like touch subsystem is logging all the touch events and when the log is full it cannot write into it. Since it resolves after reboot I'd suggest looking for that log file somewhere inside `/tmp` directory. List all the files with `ls -lS` (or `ls -l --sort=size`) to ease the task of finding the culprit file of size 6400 bytes. If not in `/tmp` then try usual `/var/logs` directory.

And then you can automate the deletion of that file with cron, e.g.:

```
30 * * * * rm /var/log/touch_log
```

Comment: And you can automate that task in crontab if you found the issue

Comment: Yup, totally missed that point I had initially. Thanks @irsu85, updated answer